# Rules in lint.xml are ignored after updating Android gradle plugin from 2.2.3 to 2.3.0

Tags: android, lint, build-tools

In my project I have a `lint.xml` file (in the root of the application module directory). It is a simple one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <!--needed by retrofit, because in it okio.Okio is referencing java.nio.file, but it is not included in Android-->
    <issue id="InvalidPackage" severity="warning" />
</lint>
```

It all use to work as expected until I did the following upgrades:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 -> com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0
```

With the v2.3.0 of the plugin, the `lint.xml` is ignored and the build fails with InvalidPackage lint error.

If I add lint configuration in the build file directly:

```
lintOptions {
    warning 'InvalidPackage'
}
```

It again works fine, so to me it looks that the issue is related to reading the `lint.xml` file.

Anyone else had this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Adding specific file name to the `lintOptions` config in the `build.gradle` also makes the build pass, so it looks that the issue is related to the file name or path:

```
lintOptions {
    lintConfig file('lint.xml')
}
```